# Using php's upload multiple files without overwriting previous selections

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I am using the upload multiple files example here.

http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload

Which I have got to work fine, but is there a way to make it behave more like wetransfer(https://www.wetransfer.com/) as in you can keep adding files to upload without actually saving (unsure how wetranser does it).

I know you could keep submitting but I want to get a list of files before submitting so we are not storing unused files on the server e.g. storing them in temp first.

Is this possible?

Currently I have this:

```
<label for="filesToUpload">Choose your artwork</label>
<input type="file" name="artwork_file[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" onchange="makeFileList();"/>

    function makeFileList() {
        //get the input
        var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');

        //for every file...
        var list_of_files = "";
        for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {
            //add to list
            list_of_files += '<div class="single_uploaded_file"><span>'+input.files[x].name+'</span></div><!--.single_uploaded_file-->';
        }
        jQuery('#file_list').html(list_of_files);
    }
```

Comment: The best solution would be if you investigate how this works behind the scenes and code your own upload. It's not as difficult as you think and gives you the chance to customize everything to it's fullest.

Comment: I don't think that that is possible, because you need to store them somewhere, what you could do is delete them afterwards. I think wetransfer also stores the files on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply's, I did have the idea of storing them temporally in my own created temp folder and deleting them afterwords but I was wondering if there was some other way of doing this natively because the multiple file upload is almost 90% there it's just that when you select more files it overwrites your previously selected one's.